# Platform events and Chatter Posts

Tags: chatter, platform-event, connect-api

I am subscribing to platform events in apex trigger. In the trigger I am trying to post to user's chatter feed using Chatter Connect API.
I am aware that in this case the context is "Automated Process". When executing Chatter Connect REST API, I am receving error:
Insufficient Privileges: The Connect API is not enabled for this user type.

If I replace chatter REST API calls with insert on FeedItem, chatter post works successfully.

I need to work with chatter connect APIs as I have a complicated chatter post format, involving EntityLink, Rich Text, images etc..

Does anyone know how to use Chatter Connect REST APi for "Automated Process" user context ?
I also tried running the code as "without sharing" but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "Automated Process" user doesn't have access to Chatter REST APIs. So only option is to use DML on FeedItem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can insert a custom object with serialized chatter message as "Automated Process".

Then you can schedule a batch as Admin (e.g. running every hour) which will deserialize message and post it via Chatter Connect REST API.